# How to change the value of xml using XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
<AddedParts NAME="AddedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<Part>
<ProcurementType>make</ProcurementType>
<CountryOfOrigin/>
</Part>
</AddedParts>

<ChangedParts NAME="ChangedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<Part>
<ProcurementType>make</ProcurementType>
<CountryOfOrigin/>
</Part>
<Part>
<ProcurementType>buy</ProcurementType>
<CountryOfOrigin/>
</Part>
</ChangedParts>
<DeletedParts NAME="DeletedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<Part>
<ProcurementType>singlesource</ProcurementType>
<CountryOfOrigin/>
</Part>
<Part>
<ProcurementType>make</ProcurementType>
<CountryOfOrigin/>
</Part>
</DeletedParts>
```

I want to Change The **CountryOfOrigin** and  **ProcurementType** on the basis of **ProcurementType** .
The transformation required is as follows 
For ProcurementType

- make ---> m
- buy ----->P
- singlesource -->P
- opensource -->P

For CountryOfOrigin 
If ProcurementType is

- make -->> MX
- buy ----->US
- singlesource -->US
- opensource -->US

For this, I have applied.

```
<xsl:template match="CountryOfOrigin">
        <countryOfOrigin>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='make'">MX</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='buy'">US</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='singlesource'">US</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='opensource'">US</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </countryOfOrigin>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Part/ProcurementType">
        <procurementType>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='make'">M</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='buy'">P</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='singlesource'">P</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="../../Part/ProcurementType='opensource'">P</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </procurementType>
    </xsl:template>
```

It is Not working , Whatever first I Apply in XSL it is replicated for whole contents.
Need Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="ProcurementType">
    <procurementType>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".='make'">M</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='buy'">P</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='singlesource'">P</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='opensource'">P</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </procurementType>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CountryOfOrigin">
    <countryOfOrigin>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../ProcurementType='make'">MX</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../ProcurementType='buy'">US</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../ProcurementType='singlesource'">US</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../ProcurementType='opensource'">US</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </countryOfOrigin>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="Part[ProcurementType='make']">
    <Part>
        <ProcurementType>M</ProcurementType>
        <CountryOfOrigin>MX</CountryOfOrigin>
    </Part>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Part[ProcurementType='buy']">
    <Part>
        <ProcurementType>P</ProcurementType>
        <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
    </Part>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Part[ProcurementType='singlesource' or ProcurementType='opensource']">
    <Part>
        <ProcurementType>P</ProcurementType>
        <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
    </Part>
</xsl:template>
```